# MessageQueue dropping message after previous message sent too quickly

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, message-queue

I have a Windows Service and Office Add-In communicating over a private MessageQueue, I've used [this MSDN Library example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.receivecompleted.aspx) to implement EventHandlers on each side.

I've added a button within the Add-In to send a message. It successfully sends it once, but if you click the button again too quickly before some of the threads exit, the message doesn't get sent through.

Could this be caused by the Eventhandlers, or any processing happening on the receiving side? I've tried calling `BeginReceive` before processing the message, but it hasn't seemed to make a difference.

If there's any other IPC methods that require less resources but don't require too much implementation, I'm definitely open to suggestions!

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  There is non in this question.